# AmbiguiousViewMatcException when testing Android app with Espresso

Tags: android, listview, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am testing one of my Android apps that has a viewpager. The ViewPager has 2 fragments. Both these framents are using the same xml as layout. This xml has a ListView in it.

When I try to lookup the ListView using

```
onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listview))
                .atPosition(4)
                .perform(click());"
```

I get an AmbiguiousViewMatcException meaning that I am trying to perform ViewAction on a view whose duplicate has been found by Espresso.

I came across solution where I couldnt identify ListView by passing

```
           .inAdapterView(withDesciption("desc"))
```

but as I am using the same xml layout, this is again going to cause the same exception. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You're forgot to tell Espresso which exactly element are you looking for. At 4th position there might be more than one views. It might be `TextView` and `ImageView` - Espresso sees two views so he tells you about by error.

To fix an issue, use `.inChildView()` matcher to say Espresso which view is interesting for you.

Here is an example code:

```
onData(anything())
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listview))
                .atPosition(4)
                .inChildView(withId(R.id.image))
                .perform(click());
```

Comment: I think the questions is not clear. As I have 2 fragments, how do I tell Espresso that I want to grab the listview in 1st fragment.

Comment: could  you describe me your fragments - `ListView`? Are they the same? Is it possible to change their `listview` id to `listview1` and `listView2`?

Comment: the best way to help you would be if you edit your post and put xml of layout with tese two fragments

Comment: Not possible to give different IDs. Like I mentioned, I am reusing the same xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isDescendantOfA` to pinpoint the `ListView` like this:

```
onData(anything())
  .inAdapterView(allOf(
      isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.fragment1)), 
      withId(R.id.listview)))
    .atPosition(4)
    .perform(click());
```

Comment: Hi Chiuki, there is a little problem here. The ViewPager doesnt let me assign an ID when instantiating the fragment. All the variables that I need access to override behavior are private. Any pointers?

Comment: It tuns out that there is no way to find out a fragment by ID. Viable way would be to pin-point the fragment using Tag but when using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, I cannot access related variables as well. I may have to copy entire instantiateItem() method from FragmentStatePagerAdapter but that is an ugly solution.